# How to choose between two versions of ruby on Mac OSX Mavericks

Tags: ruby, macos

I have 1.8 and 2.0 installed on my system. How I can delete the old one or Use the new one to work with gems?

Comment: How did you install 2 ruby versions? Did you use something like `railsinstaller` or `jewelrybox`?

Comment: You can install additional Ruby versions with [ruby-install](https://github.com/postmodern/ruby-install), [ruby-build](https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build) or [RVM](https://rvm.io/).

Comment: @SreekanthGS OS X 10.9 ships with both

Comment: @Stefan I wanted to know how Koffer installed them.

Comment: the second one I believe I install it with brew install ruby, But are inside library in system.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to install [RVM](http://rvm.io/rvm/basics) and then select version 2.0 like this:

```
rvm use 2.0.0
```

You can check which version is being used with

```
ruby -v
```

Comment: I try with rbenv and bundler but I have problems with gem versions, permissions and ruby versions.

Comment: run `rvm requirements`

Comment: But then you will *die*